# .show() not working on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am totally clueless, i don't know why this happening. I am trying to display the right section of HTML after page load. By default i set `display:none;` in CSS. And want to show the page during page load.

This is how i tried:

```
var f_e = $('#nav > li > a').first();

    f_e.addClass('active');
    f_e.next().slideToggle();

    // Right section that make the div display block
    $('#unigem-quickstart').show();
```

But its not working, here is the full code with [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jogesh_pi/muE4x/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you have two different instances of an `ID`. (This being `unigem-quickstart`) so it's only calling the first one (which is an `a` tag). You need to name it something else. (There should be only 1 ID of something!)

Comment: Ahh, you are right. I tried to check this with console.log( $('#unigem-quickstart').length ) that return to me 1, then i though their was only one. Thanks man now it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('div#unigem-quickstart').show();
```

You used the id twice